# A math question related to creating a risk formula..

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I'm not using correct terminology, or this isn't clear, I will gladly edit/clarify.

I'm trying to figure out how to create method or formula(s) to produce a score based on 4 variables, all real numbers.  More accurately the score would be the product of the proportions of these variables:
Risk(%), Return (%), time (hours), and liquidity (integer).   The score can then be used to sort a list.   This is easier to explain with just 2 of those variables, Risk and Return.  Risk is the probability of failure.
EX:

```
            Risk        Return  
 Trade1:   .5                1            
 Trade2:    1               .5
```

Score for trade 1 = (1/.5) * 1 = 2

Score for trade2=  (1/1) * .5 = .5

Trade 1 scores higher as it's getting twice the return for half the risk.  The calculations should not refer to the other trade, only to variables in the same trade.
My questions are:
1)   I would like the proportion to scale depending on the magnitude of the numbers. If the returns were swapped, the scores would be the same:

```
            Risk        Return  
 Trade3:   .5                .5            
 Trade4:    1                1
```

Score for trade 3 = (1/.5) * .5 = 1

Score for trade 4=  (1/1) * 1 = 1

Since the risk is low(less than X where x=1.5, I would rather choose the trade with a higher return.  The scale of the risk numbers (when small) should negate the proportional effect of the risk on the return, but as the scale of the risk numbers increases it should start gradually increasing the proportional effect of the risk on the return.  Also, even if the scale is small, if the increase in risk proportion is large it should also increase the effect on return (require a slightly higher return) :

```
            Risk        Return  
 Trade3:   .2                .5            
 Trade4:   .8               .6   is required
```

Choose trade 4 -   4x risk for a 1.2% increase in return,   if 5x risk , then 1.4% increase in return.. once a risk number cross 1.5%:

```
            Risk        Return  
 Trade5:   1                .5            
 Trade6:   2                1.25 is required to choose trade6..
```

If we hit some max risk(say 10) it should then increase faster:

```
            Risk            Return
 Trade 7:   5                 .5          
 Trade 8:   10                 5
```

I'd also like to include liquidity and time, so the ideal trade has low risk, high liquidity, short time, and high return.  The problem with using proportions without somehow considering the size of the other numbers is that 1 variable could score a bad trade (too high of risk) higher.  I'm trying to figure out how to offset that effect. Of course the same kinds of relationships would apply for the other variables, for example for small risk between two trades (.2, .6), and everything else even, I would take .6 risk if the liquidity was higher, or time was shorter, etc..

Sorry for this long question.. I really appreciate any advice/tips..

Answer (score 0):

This is a very non-mathematical question.  If you define risk and return correctly, it makes sense to rate investments on return/risk, but even that is hard.  How accurate are your risk and return numbers?  Time and liquidity (how are they different-you don't say) are very different.  If I have a sure high return, unless I need the money soon I should be happy with a long time horizon.  One approach is t say I need some amount of my portfolio available within a short time-then I use that as a cutoff and pick the best risk/return with that horizon. Then I have another portion with a longer horizon, so can have more options for it and so on.

It sounds like you are hoping for a magic mathematical formula that will tell you what to do. In fact, there are *many* formulas.  You need to decide what you want, then find the formula that reflects that.

Comment: I'm not asking for many formulas, I suppose I'm asking for a way to reduce the increasing effect of one variable on another, but based on the magnitude of the increasing variable.  The context is investment related yes. As to whether or not my investment is any good or if the risk is accurate is not the point.  I just want to sort 500 potential combinations of these variables so they can be easily deciphered, period.    In any case it seems creating a polynomial to model the relationship I want for each variable seems to make sense...